# Converting Stream<IntStream> to a single IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a `List<String>` to an `IntStream`. Suppose that my list is like `["abc", "de", "fghi"]`. Then the `IntStream` that I want is like `1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3`. (The number of occurrences of a number `i` in the `IntStream` depends on the length of `i`th string in the given list)

I wrote the following method for that (it won't compile):

```java
private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
    final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    return list.stream()
            .map(str -> {
                        atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                        return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                                .map(i -> atomicInteger.get());
                    }); // Now I don't understand how can I convert this Stream<IntStream> to a single IntStream 

}
```

But I don't understand how can I convert can I convert a `Stream<IntStream>` to a single `IntStream`. (My guess is that we can use `flatMap` somehow, but I don't exactly get how to use it.)

I'm using `IntStream` instead of `Stream<Integer>` to avoid auto-boxing and make my whole system more efficient.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding over the comment of @JB_Nizet

The method that I need to use is [flatMapToInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
    final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    return list.stream()
            .flatMapToInt(str -> {
                atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                        .map(i -> atomicInteger.get());
            });
}
```

Comment: Could you give us more details about what do you want to achieve? usage of AtomicInteger indicates that you might be doing something the hard way (unnecessarily)

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek I simply want to get the `IntStream`. It's more of a playing to learn about Java-8's stream-API, rather then doing something useful. But I'd really appreciate if you could do something where we don't use the `AtomicInteger`. It looks ugly to me too.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to achieve? I see that you simply discard all strings from the input list and replace it with AtomicInteger generated sequence?

Comment: That's what I want to do, the contents of the string Strings don't matter, rather each string's length matters, and on the basis of that I need to generate a sequence.

Comment: How about this `IntStream.range(0,list.size())
                .flatMap(i-> IntStream.range(0, list.get(i).length()).map(j->i+1));`

Answer (score 6):

The other solution would be like this:

```
IntStream result =  IntStream.range(0,list.size())
                             .flatMap(i-> IntStream.range(0, list.get(i)
                                                                 .length())
                                                   .map(j->i+1));
```

Comment: I think I almost wrote a similar version with `List<Integers` though `private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).length(); j++) {
                integerList.add(i + 1);
            }
        }
        return integerList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i);
    }`

Comment: I clearly prefer this one over the not so nice side effect using the `AtomicInteger`. A variant I’d find a bit more natural would be `IntStream.range(0, list.size()).flatMap(index -> list.get(index).chars().map(ch -> index + 1))`, but maybe not so efficient and certainly a matter of taste.

Comment: @OleV.V. `...list.get(index).chars().map(ch -> index + 1)...` It's better due to concise than mine.

Comment: Feel free to adopt. Glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to use `flatMapToInt`:

```
private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
    final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    return list.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(str -> {
            atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
            return IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                .map(i -> atomicInteger.get());
        });
}
```

but I'd rethink what you'd like to achieve here. Now, each `String` in the initial list will be replaced with a number taken from `AtomicInteger` (and this will be repeated String.length() times for each String):

```
getSingleIntStream(Arrays.asList("a", "bc")).forEach(System.out::println); // 1 2 2
```

I assume you wanted to number each char from every `String`:

```
private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    return list.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(str -> IntStream.range(0, str.length())
            .map(i -> atomicInteger.incrementAndGet()));
}

// 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct about `flatMap`, as Hadi J already shows in a good answer. I just wanted to offer my variant of the same:

```
private static IntStream getSingleIntStream(List<String> list) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, list.size())
            .flatMap(i -> list.get(i - 1).chars().map(ch -> i));
}
```

You may find this version more natural or concise. In any case both versions have the advantage of avoiding the `AtomicInteger` and the side effect of the stream pipeline on it. A stream pipeline should be free from side effects.

Let’s also see it in action:

```
    List<String> list = List.of("abc", "de", "fghi");
    int[] nums = getSingleIntStream(list).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

When you need the index of an element inside a stream, the general trick is to start out from an `IntStream` of the indices and inside your stream pipeline make the lookup of the elements from the indices (`list.get(i - 1)`). In this case I am (unconventionally) using 1-based indices because you wanted your resulting numbers to start from 1. So we need to subtract 1 in the list lookup.